# ajax doesn't update on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have a problem with my code, it's a like button. It shows the number of likes. If user haven't voted yet (cookie) he can click and counter increases. Problem is counter doesn't update on first click (if i deactivate cookie check and vote several times) on next refresh is everything updated. It seems some count happens before insert in the backend. I suppose probem is in JavaScript, ajax post cross domain works but gives error that's why "error: setCookieAndUpdateButton()"

here is my frontend code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


<div><a id="like_button" href="#">Like</a></div>
<script>
var url = "http://thumbs-up.some-server.com/";
var appName = "next_test";

document.write("<script src=\"" + url + "jquery.cookie.js\"><\/script>");
$(document).ready(function(){
  updateButton();
  $("#like_button").click(function(){
      if ($.cookie(appName + "_voted") == "true") {return;}
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          crossDomain: true,
          url: url + "increase_counter.php",
          data: {referrer: appName},
          success: setCookieAndUpdateButton(),
          error: setCookieAndUpdateButton()
      });
  });
});
function setCookieAndUpdateButton()
{
    updateButton();
    $.cookie(appName + "_voted", "true", {expires: 20*365});
}
function updateButton()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback4jquery',
        url: url + "get_counter_for_referrer.php",
        data: {referrer: appName},
        success: function (json) {
          if ($.cookie(appName + "_voted") != "true"){
            $("#like_button").html("<a id=\"like_button\" href=\"#\"><img src=\"" + url + "like.png\">Good to know " + json.count + "x</a>")
          }
          else{
            $("#like_button").html("<span id=\"like_button\"><img src=\"" + url + "like.png\">Good to know "  + json.count + "x</span>");
            $('#like_button').unbind('click');
          }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first ajax call change your code like this:

```
 success: setCookieAndUpdateButton,
 error: setCookieAndUpdateButton
```

without `()` in both of them

Comment: Yes my colleague told me, it should be function name not a function call. I'm just learning javascript by doing, don't know much details :)